# Different chemistry of batteries in operation

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, charger, load, bms

I had an idea of using different chemistry of batteries as shown in the schematic figure [image: schematic]
Is that possible to design a system in that way. According to the design, I am using all the evaluation boards.
Buck charge controller for charging the batteries
Boost converter for stepping up voltage
ORing controller to share the common load bus.
Can some one please guide me whether that can be done or it?
I am sure there will be lot of power loss and decrease in efficiency.
Can some help me in understanding it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah totally possible. Whether it's right for you, is up to you.

Comment: @user253751. Thanks for your information.Can there be more losses. Its an idea but I really dnt know how to go forward. As of now I was looking some buck charger controllers, boost converter and ORing controller.

Comment: Can I suggest that 24V lead acid would make life a lot simpler.

Comment: I am a bit worried about that 9V lead-acid battery.

Comment: @SimonB  can you please explain me what you mean I did not understand

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you for response. What you mean is instead of using 9V we can directly use buck charger to charge 24V battery then they can be supplied to load bus then there will be elimination of the boost converter

Comment: @KranthiKumarBanala You're proposing to drop 36V to charge a 9V battery (which is odd as each cell in a lead acid battery is 2V), and then boost it back up again to give 24V.  Why put such a low voltage battery in the middle?  You can get or make a 24V lead acid battery.

Comment: i had a simple doubt, can I eliminate boost converters. Simply charging 24V batteries from charger then connecting the ideal diodes and batteries give supply directly to the load bus. Does this work or will damage the system

Answer (score 0):

If you just take generic off the shelf converters and hook them up that way they will likely feed into each other and cook each other.  You can put diodes on their outputs so they can't back feed each other, but you lose some voltage in the diode and output voltage will vary a bit with current.  Even if you do this, they only correct for voltage at their output and one will inevitably maintain a slightly higher output voltage than the other.  This will tend to cause it to take almost all the load until it can no longer sustain its output at which point the other converter's voltage will be higher and it will take all the load.  It might not rapidly burn out if both converters are sized to support the full load, but it's not an ideal situation.

Paralleling power converters isn't particularly easy unless they are designed to work in parallel.  The higher the power the bigger the challenge.  If you're actually designing the converters yourself, you have to make them communicate with each other to balance load.  If you're good enough to do that, you can probably handle the additional challenge of doing it with two different input voltages.  Doing it with a high capacity or high power system, especially with Lithium ion Cells, or simply ensuring isolation and other factors will make the device fail safe for a commercial product is probably in the domain of engineers.  There is not necessarily an intrinsic loss of efficiency, just a big engineering challenge.

For a hobby version you weren't going to sell, you could probably do it with two relatively responsive isolated voltage converters and a microcontroller monitoring output voltage and current on both converters.  Challenge is increasing load on one converter while decreasing it on the other when both have different input voltage and duty cycle without too much effect on output voltafge, possibly while load is changing.  For a hobby version you could probably avoid the insane math skills needed by writing a program to experimentally determine values for a look up table and interpolating between values on the lookup table to correct imbalances.  If you have a lot of advanced math and Calculus skill, doing things the other way may look less intimidating for you than me.

As some other notes, the system would have to monitor both input battery voltages to ensure proper operation if one drops out and ensure low voltage cut off.  Because you'd need a microcontroller to begin with and you have the processing power available, it would probably be wise to build it to allow non-50/50 load balancing as well.

Comment: I believe that's what the "ORing controller" (read OR-ing, like boolean OR) is for. It's a diode or ideal diode that prevents backfeeding.

Comment: @user253751 When I looked them up it looked like they give either/or functionality but no balancing.  I suppose maybe thats all thats needed.

Comment: I just mean they wouldn't be damaged

Comment: @user253751 Ah.  I should have noted he already had back feed covered but I had half of it written by the time I looked up the ORing controllers anyway.  They're new for me so at first glance I just saw that the converters and controllers were they weren't set up to communicate.  It's good to know the part name.  MOSFET ideal diodes are still on my list of things to figure out or I would have suggested one, not realizing it was in the ORing controller lol.

Comment: @KH thanks a lot for your information. Actaully, I am not desiging my own converter. I am just buying some modules from industries like Analog, Texas, Renesas, Maxim. I read that charger controllers can be connected in that way taking same supply with different outputs for different batteries. Then we use boost to step up. Generally, what I study is if we connect converter modules in parallel we use droop method or current sharing method in that case we dnt use idea diodes or ORing. If we use ORing modules or idea diodes I think no need of droop method or current control.

Comment: One main doubt is that we see that stepping up battery voltages like 9V, 10V, 12V using boost converter to 24V. We even using 24V load bus. In my opinion, do we require to control the voltage of boost converter. We need 24V nominal output from input range say 8V to 16V. In the market, we find some evaluation boards which take input from 8V to 16V and give exactly 24V. So, directly the board is converting to 24V whatever input. I am thinking that there is no need of controlling the output of boost converter. Is this correct or not?

Comment: I dnt have much knowledge about using ideal diodes or ORing which uses external MOSFET. After two boost converters share the common load 24V using whatevr ideal diodes or ORing. How the load is distributed here? What kind of power distribution we expect here? These are my doubts. I hope everyone understands my English.

Comment: If you only use backfeed blocking, you still can have load sharing issues, but you can still either decide which is the primary converter and give it slightly higher output or force current sharing with a bit of series resistance which I'm guessing is what you refer to as droop method, but I don't really like that personally because it's sloppy.  It would be very hard to find two off the shelf converters so well matched in output that one didn't dominate.

Comment: @KH any ideas please.

Comment: Which battery do you actually want to drain first?

Comment: As we are using strings with separate converters. Can both be working simultaneously?

Comment: They can be ON simultaneously, but they're unlikely to balance load effectively.  It's possible but not likely they will balance load to some degree if their outputs are close enough and droops enough with load.  It's more likely one will dominate, the two logical decisions I can see that you can make from this are to either force them to share or choose which one drains first.